# How to make a slot machine text effect in css and/or javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a banner that I created that I want to animate with a lot machine effect: http://codepen.io/abek/pen/rLAmwr

What JS tools or CSS techniques would help create that effect?

```
  <div class="select-a-game ">
    <ul class="select-a-game-name text-center">
      <li class="sagn-dark-blue">S</li>
      <li class="sagn-dark-grey">E</li>
      <li class="sagn-orange">L</li>
      <li class="sagn-red">E</li>
      <li class="sagn-grey">C</li>
      <li class="sagn-dark-blue">T</li>
      <li class="sagn-black">A</li>
      <li class="sagn-dark-grey">G</li>
      <li class="sagn-dark-blue">A</li>
      <li class="sagn-grey">M</li>
      <li class="sagn-red">E</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried before asking? I'd assume that your answer will involve applying an `overflow: hidden;` style to your `<li>` elements, wrapping the individual letters in a `<div>`, and animating the inside div's `top` property to move it vertically. Once the `top` property got to a certain number (and the text was out of the bottom of the `<li>`), you'd reset it's position to a negative number (so it would be off the top). Good luck.

Comment: You mean like a slot machine? Easy with 2d animation, a nightmare with 3d transforms if you like the solution cross browser compatible.
I'd do this with a jquery transform library.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, this is the important part here, the JS function.

```
$('li').click(function(event){
$( event.target ).css({ perspective: 200, rotateY: 240 });
});
```

This is dependent on the jQuery and jq transform library.

This is just a demo and you can play around with the numbers.You did not state if you want them all to fire in sequence, I just made the easiest implementation, function is called on click.

Codepen

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/LkByag